# How to edit/drop analyzers in CrateDB?

Tags: cratedb

In CrateDB's documentation: https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/sql/statements/index.html

there's no reference as to how to delete an analyzer or to edit it?

I have a sample query, and executing it multiple times gives no errors:

```
CREATE ANALYZER myanalyzer (
   TOKENIZER whitespace,
   TOKEN_FILTERS (
     lowercase,
     kstem
   ),
   CHAR_FILTERS (
     html_strip
   )
 );
```

Returns:

```
CREATE ANALYZER OK, 1 row affected (0.003 sec)
```

Does this mean that `myanalyzer` once created can't be deleted? 
Will it be right to say that one can edit it, by executing the edited query again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest documentation, they have now mentioned:

> **Note**
>
> Altering analyzers is not supported yet.

https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/general/ddl/fulltext-indices.html

Answer (score 1):

yes, unfortunately there is at the moment no way to drop or edit an analyzer.